# answer phone call & display button iphone

Tags: iphone, button, user-interface

I'm new to iphone developing. I want create a app just like following way.

When phone call is coming to the phone & user answer it. then display the button. after the call end button is disappear.

is there any way to do it. help me

thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible with a non-jailbroken iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS doesn't allow access to most telephony functions, so you can't do things like display a button when a user answers a call.